# Use awk to return adjacent match value from csv file

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to search a string from a csv file and if a match is found then return corresponding $N columns value, otherwise return N/A. Say my csv file name is Book1.csv and the content is like,

```
a, this, that, those
b, something, many thing, anything
c, duck, goose
d, rock, paper, scissor
```

My goal is to search say `c` and print corresponding column say 2nd columns value from it. In this case the output will be `duck`

I've tried to use this command `awk -F "c\"*,\"*" '{print $2}' /home/linuxmint/Desktop/test/Book2.csv`

This works however it also return non matching value as blank output. I only need matching output in this case.

Would appreciate any help on this. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Perhaps `awk -F',' '/^c/ {print $2}' file.csv` ?

Comment: To get "N/A" when the output is blank, maybe use an if/else statement: `awk_query=$(awk -F',' '/^c/ {print $3}' test.txt) && if [[ "$awk_query" ]]; then echo "$awk_query"; else echo "N/A"; fi`  And, to try a non-existing column: `awk_query=$(awk -F',' '/^c/ {print $4}' test.txt) && if [[ "$awk_query" ]]; then echo "$awk_query"; else echo "N/A"; fi`

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, if I want to save the output in a variable instead of printing it right way what should be done?

Comment: Would you try: `result=$(grep "^c" Book1.csv | cut -d, -f2 | grep . || echo "N/A")`

Comment: @Some53, Does your actual Input_file is same as shown samples? Or it could have other values too?

Comment: @tshion, Thanks for your reply, unfortunately it's not returning anything

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, It could have any value. Those are just sample.

Comment: So far the code from @jared_mamrot is working flawlessly, but I need to store the output as a variable and use it later on.

Comment: @tshiono sorry, your code is working just fine now. The issue was. I created the csv file through MS office, and when ever I tried to match the 1st row `a` it was resulting N/A but after creating the csv file in Libra office. It's working now

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Good to know it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var=$(awk -F, -v col=3 -v srch="c" '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if ($i==srch) { if ( $(col)!="") { print $(col);fnd=1 } } } } END { if (fnd!=1) { print "N/A" } }' /home/linuxmint/Desktop/test/Book2.csv)
```

Pass the comma separated field you want to output as a variable "col" and the string to search for as a variable "srch". Loop through each comma separated field and check if it matches srch. If it does print the field designated by col and also set a variable "fnd" to 1. At the end of processing the lines, if fnd is not 1, print "N/A" Read the result into a variable "var"

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's showing Syntax error: `"(" unexpected`

Comment: Apologies. I forgot the $ before the opening bracket!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this works. However, if there is no value in the respective column then it returns blank value instead of N/A

Comment: OK, I've amended the answer to take account of blank fields

Answer (score 2):

Although @Raman Sailopal solution works, I just wanted share few more answers which were posted by @jared_mamrot

```
awk_query=$(awk -F',' '/\ycom.google.android.gm\y/ {print $2}' Book2.csv) && if [ "$awk_query" ]; then awk_query="$awk_query"; else  awk_query="N/A"; fi

echo $awk_query
```

and @tshiono

```
result=$(grep -wr "com.google.android.gm" Book2.csv | cut -d, -f2 | grep . || echo "N/A")

echo $result
```

EDIT:
I've updated the solution when a user might need to match whole word. Like,

```
com.google.android.gm   Gmail
com.google.android.gms  Google Play Services
```